# Caching SQLite tables using a Perl cache module

Tags: perl, sqlite, caching

I'm using an SQLite database to store 10,000 products

I'm querying it at least 3 times in each CGI request

Each query takes about 10 milliseconds

1. Would it be better implemented using some cache like CHI?
2. Is it possible or a mean is a proven "best practice"?
3. The cache will keep alives during the webserver is UP? (Apache)
4. Or it will be rebuilt at each CGI request? (I'm using mod_perl)

Comment: I deduce from your question that you think that 10 ms is too long? Did you ever try optimizing those queries (such as using a single transaction, or using proper indexes)?

Answer (score 1):

1. You've not provided sufficient info to determine that.
2. Query result caching is a practice. Best practice depends on the
   context.
3. Depends on how you implement your cache.
4. Is it mod_perl, or one of the various CGI adaptors for mod_perl.

You have not talked about how you use the data.

1. Do you query the same data in each of the three queries?
2. Do you query the same data on subsequent queries/requests?
3. Which queries are you trying to eliminate, and why?